# Get value from a javascript function in VBscript

Tags: vbscript, domdocument, javascript

I'd like to get the execute a javascript function using IE and get its value in VBScript. I have the following VBscript code (the solution has to be in vbscript):

```
Dim oIE: Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
With oIE
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate (url)
End With
Do Until oIE.ReadyState = 4
    wscript.sleep 100
Loop
oIE.Document.parentWindow.execScript("alert(function());") 'Get Return value
```

How can I get the value of "function()"? I'm aware that [execscript always returns null](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536420%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I could have the javascript write an element, and then fetch its value, but I'm sure there's a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a variable in javascript. The variable can be loaded with any value, object or function (as in this example). In VBScript, you can retrieve it as a member of oIE.Document.parentWindow:

```
oIE.Document.parentWindow.execScript("var ultimateAnswer = function(){return 42;}")
msgbox oIE.Document.parentWindow.ultimateAnswer()
```